# Haskell hello world won't compile

Tags: haskell

What is wrong with this code? Trying to do a basic haskell hello world.

```
module Main
( hello )
where

hello :: [Char] -> [Char]
hello p = "Hello " ++ p ++ "!"

main =
  let msg = hello "World"
  putStrLn msg
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing a `do`:

```
main = do
  let msg = hello "World"
  putStrLn msg
```

You'll also want to export your `main`:

```
module Main ( main ) where
```

Since this is the main module, there is no need to export `hello`.

Comment: Or, without do: `main = putStrLn (hello "World")`

Comment: Or `main = putStrLn $ hello "World"`

Comment: Or `main = (putStrLn . hello) "World"`

Comment: Or `main = putStrLn . hello $ "World"`

Answer (score 7):

You're missing a `in`:

```
main = let msg = hello "World" in putStrLn msg
```